# Processing all Packets generated by a browser

Tags: network-programming

I want to write a program which *Controls* all the web browsing activities on PC.
i.e. Checking all the websites users go to, filtering some of them, ... .

But I have no idea how to capture all the packets, processing them, and even act to some (think of filtering unwanted sites).

Any help, sample code, open source program...?

Comment: do you care about language we will choose for you? Or OS? Or anything?

Comment: not about language but I prefer C or C#. Windows is the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different levels you can put yourself in the middle of the communication:

1. By implementing a proxy and having the browser connect to the proxy
2. By implementing a firewall/snooper and handling the raw packets
3. By implementing a network driver and handling the raw packets

IMHO, number 1 is easiest. Look at [SQUID](http://www.squid-cache.org/) for an example. Number 2 is doable too, take a look at [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). You could take a look at the [Click Modular Router](http://read.cs.ucla.edu/click/click) for option number 3.

Depending on the browser, maybe a simple browser plugin could do?

Comment: Thanks. I want it to be Browser independent.

Comment: is Fiddler open source by any chance?

Comment: @MBZ: Nope, but wireshark is, you can download its sourcecode.

Comment: However, if you don't want to edit the browser (and thus, no proxy), my personal experience would advise you to go with the Click Modular Router.